# Can not view all tables in *.accdb file

Tags: ms-access, vba

I suppose that my question will be considered silly, but I'm really stuck.

How can I view all tables in the *.accdb file?

I use Microsoft Access from Office 14 to open and edit that file. Then I go to the `Database Tools` tab and select `Relationships`, where I expect to see all the tables, but actually I can't.

I see there some tables and even saved queries. And some of these queries use tables, that I can not find.

I'm newbie to the `Access`, but have to make some edits to the database.

**UPD:**
Somehow I've managed to view necessary tables through the maze of `Object dependencies`. Is there a more simple way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like some tables are set as Hidden and you don't have the View Hidden Objects setting checked.

Press F11 to show the navigation pane if it is hidden. While that is open, right-click the top of the bar and choose Navigation Options. In the next screen, you'll see an area Display Options, whose first checkbox is Show Hidden Objects. This will allow you to see greyed icons for hidden tables in the navigation pane. It also adds the names of hidden tables to the "Show table..." box in the Relationships.

Answer (score 1):

In relationships right click anywhere in the empty box, show table, select all tables, click add

Comment: Maybe, it's strange, but I've done it. And it all remains the same. For example, I have a query that makes a select from a table `ProductNames`. But this table is not present neither on the `Relationships` view, nor in the `Show table` list. It's a kind of mystery.

Comment: Can you see the tables in design view?

Comment: Only those, which are on the relationships view. In the VBA code the tables I need are opened through `OpenRecordset` method.

Comment: If you can't see the tables in design or datasheet view the tables are either hidden or they have been deleted

Comment: But the query returns data correctly. So maybe they are really hidden. Maybe, You know how to show hidden record?

Comment: I'm not sure what is the exact line but I'm sure you are able to do a little google search

Comment: That's why I'm here:) Googling wasn't successfull.

Comment: For that query which uses `FROM ProductNames`, have you confirmed there is not a saved query named `ProductNames`?

Comment: @HansUp, nope, there's no such query